# Scheme program freezes with no exceptions

Tags: scheme, racket

Ok, i'm taking this scheme class on the university, and we just got our first assignment. I'm experiencing this wierd thing though. Sometimes the program will freeze, do absolutely nothing without giving me any sort of warning as to why this is...

Take the following procedure:

```
(define (calc-week-day y1 m d w y2) ; anta y2 > y1
  (define (days-between-months m1 m2 y)
    (if (= m1 m2)
        0
        (+ (month-length y m1) (days-between-months (+ m1 1) m2 y))))
  (define (days-between-years y1 y2)
    (if (= y1 y2) 
        0
        (+ (year-length y1) (days-between-years (+ y1 1) y2))))
  (define (days-til-months-end d m y)
    (- (month-length y m) d))
  (define (calculate-day day offset)
    (cond ((> day 6) (calculate-day 0 (- offset 1)))
          ((= offset 0) day)
          (else (calculate-day (+ day 1) (- offset 1)))))

  (define dager-til-nyttår (+ (days-between-months m 12 y1)
                              (days-til-months-end d 12 y1) 1))
  (define dager-fra-nyttår (+ (days-between-months 1 m y2) d 2))
  (define dager-mellom-datoer (+ dager-til-nyttår (days-between-years y1 y2)
                                 dager-fra-nyttår))

  (num->day (calculate-day (day->num w) dager-mellom-datoer)))
```

`calc-week-day` basically takes two years where `y2 > y1` always. m = month, d = day and w = day of the week (monday, tuesday...) The function figures out the difference in days between the same date in `y1` and `y2`, and figures out the day of the week in `y2` ...

This procedure doesn't work as it should. This will in fact not produce any output. However, if I remove the last digit (2) from `(define dager-fra-nyttår ...)` it works just fine and produces the day of the week to the output screen (though not the correct dates).

Anyone know why this is? (using Racket 5.2 on Mac OSX Lion)

Comment: Do you have test cases for any of your helper functions?  Do you know if any of your helper functions work? This isn't as flippant a question as it might seem at first.  I'm not convinced that calculate-day terminates under all anticipated conditions.  For example, if you pass it a day greater than 6 and an offset equal to zero, it won't terminate.

By the way, if you're using DrRacket, try pressing the Stop button.  It should tell you generally where your program was computing.  Might give a hint as to where the infinite loop is happening.

Comment: The helper was written by the proffessor, and has been used for at least a couple of years, so i presume they work as advertised even though there are no test-cases provided...

Comment: By "helper functions", I mean all the internally defined functions in calc-week-day.  Presumably, your professor didn't write those, or else what else is there for you to do?  :)  Also, when you're asking for help in tracing what looks like an infinite loop, provide sample inputs, so that people who want to help can replicate your scenario.  What inputs are you passing into calc-week-day, and if the program were working correctly, what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're stuck in an infinite loop.

My guess is that either `days-between-months` or `days-between-years` is calling itself endlessly.

For example, `days-between-months` seems to presume that `m1` <= `m2`.  But if you call it with `m1` > `m2`, it looks like it would keep calling itself "forever" -- keep trying to increment `m1` until it equals `m2`, but it never will, because it's already greater. (Well, "never", or at least for a long time until the integer value wraps around.)

Practically, there are two ways to address this.

- The "defensive programming" way is to change your `if` test from `(= m1 m2)` to `(<= m1 m2)`.  A lot of programmers would do this.
- The *Writing Solid Code* way would be to say, wait, the problem is with the caller passing nonsense values to the function: The *caller* should be fixed, rather than the function silently hiding the mistake. If you like this approach, you'd add an `assert` in a language like C, or here you could do something like `(when (> m1 m2) (error))` to deliberately cause an error. Or in Racket, you could use a `contract`, and it will complain if you try to violate the conditions you required.

After years of writing code, I prefer the second approach. But you will find good arguments both ways. Also it depends on the nature of the system you're coding, whether you prefer it to be "brittle" about failures so you can find and fix them, or muddle along as best it can. Also some people take the brittle approach in "debug" builds, and the tolerant one for the released product.

Finally, your code calls a couple functions that aren't defined in what you provided (like `month-length` and `year-length`), and the problem(s) could be there instead of or in addition to what I mentioned.

Comment: Hmm, sounds plausible. Reading this code is not as easy as reading Javascipt or Java as I'm used too, which may be why I didn't spot this myself... I'll test this when I get back from work and see if it's the answer I'm looking for. In the meantime I'll give you a vote for a great answer =)

Comment: Reading it will get easier, once your brain rewires itself. Before long you'll be able to flip between reading the `{}` languages and the `()` languages -- as easily as flipping between reading English and Norwegian. :)